# Why does this conditional statement not work and does an if-statement that seems to do the same thing work?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have this property:

```
int? firstClientID;
```

Why does this

```
firstClientID = dataRow.IsFirstClientIDNull() 
                    ? null 
                    : (int.TryParse(dataRow.FirstClientID, out tempInt) 
                        ? tempInt 
                        : 0);
```

not compile because

> type of conditional statement cannot be determined since there is no
>   implicit conversion between null and int

and does

```
if (dataRow.IsFirstClientIDNull())
    firstClientID = null;
else if (int.TryParse(dataRow.FirstClientID, out tempInt))
    firstClientID = tempInt;
else
    firstClientID = 0;
```

work? They seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Is that property supposed to be `firstClientId`?. Because, otherwise, it has no dearing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> > Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

i.e. You will need to ensure both legs of the conditional operator return the same type (i.e. cast through `Nullable<int>`).

```
firstClientID = dataRow.IsFirstClientIDNull() 
                ? (int?)null
                : (int.TryParse(dataRow.FirstClientID, out tempInt) 
                    ? tempInt 
                    : 0);
```

(The conditional operator is not really the same as an `if / then else` branch, as the conditional operator must return data of the same type, whereas `if` can do anything in each leg of the branches, with no constraints on type compatability)